# Can't establicsh WebSocket connection. Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: websocket, webrtc, cross-domain, wss, ant-media-server-sdk

I was trying to connect live streaming in my laravel application using Antmedia Streaming Server, when it comes to production the websocket is not connected. I think the browser is blocking the server url. Can anyone help ?

[image: Screenshot from the console :]

Comment: Hi @Midhun Babu,
Did you get this solved? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminMwendwaMunyoki, it works fine with direct URL of the loadbalancer. But the browser keep blocking when using CDN.